# 2 different routes on one page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hi I'm pretty new with MVC2 or MVC in general. If it's one thing I get caught up with it's routes. Like now I got this scenario. Im going from the regular site to Admin. My navigation is the same partialview on both I just do a check which data to render something like this.

```
<% if (!Request.RawUrl.Contains("Admin")){%>
<% foreach (var site in Model) { %>
<%= Html.MenuItem(site.BelongSite, "Sida", "Site", site.BelongSite) %> |
<%} %>
<%} else {%>   
<%= Html.ActionLink("Konfig", "Konfigurera", "Admin") %>
<% } %>
```

My route looks like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Admin", // Route name
                "Admin/{action}/{name}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Admin", action = "konfigurera", name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

On my View called Konfigurera I got Edit sites and they use the route above and it works great. The navigation tho dont get no action assigned to it. It's just `<a href='Admin/'>`

The navigation is in the shared folder, and it is a strongly typed. Any Ideas? I been struggling with this for about a hour now

Thanks for any input

**EDIT**

this is just one of those omg I'm so stupid moments. Ofcause the the link gone be only `<a href='Admin/'` because it's the default link (as the default values of the route). I noticed this as I put more links to the Admin navigation and they was ok. Well hope this can help anybody in the same situation as I had.

I wonder how I should do if I come up with the solution myself?

Comment: If you come up with a solution for yourself, post an answer and mark it as the solution. That way we won't see it in the unanswered list. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcause the the link gone be only `<a href='Admin/'` because it's the default link (as the default values of the route). So really no problem here Index always gone result in a "empty" link.